# Duplicate LV names after cloning a disk with clonezilla

Tags: lvm, proxmox, clonezilla

I have cloned my bare metal installation of Debian Bookworm on LVM to Proxmox VE. The cloning was done via Clonezilla (remote), disk to disk. The Disks were the same size but I'm unaware if I selected 1:1 copy or the "shrink" copy, which adapts to disk space on target. Maybe this is the result of a shrink copy? I needed multiple attempts for cloning because the `data` LV was on another HDD and could not be cloned this way. I had to completely remove this LV, the PV from the VG and the PV itself to by successfull.

Now, I seem to have duplicate LV names.

```
# lvs -a -o +devices
  LV   VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
  data server-vg -wi-ao----  <2,73t                                                     /dev/sdb1(0)
  root server-vg -wi-ao---- <62,76g                                                     /dev/sda2(512)
  root server-vg -wi-ao---- <62,76g                                                     /dev/sda2(18256)
  swap server-vg -wi-ao----   2,00g                                                     /dev/sda2(0)
  tmp  server-vg -wi-ao----  14,61g                                                     /dev/sda2(15872)
  tmp  server-vg -wi-ao----  14,61g                                                     /dev/sda2(26995)
  var  server-vg -wi-ao---- <31,38g                                                     /dev/sda2(10752)
  var  server-vg -wi-ao---- <31,38g                                                     /dev/sda2(24082)
```

They are shown with `-o +devices` option only.

```
# pvs -o +devices
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree  Devices
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(0)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(512)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(10752)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(15872)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(18256)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(24082)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m /dev/sda2(26995)
  /dev/sda2  server-vg lvm2 a--  <110,79g 36,00m
  /dev/sdb1  server-vg lvm2 a--    <2,73t     0  /dev/sdb1(0)

# vgs -o +devices
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree  Devices
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(0)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(512)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(18256)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(10752)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(24082)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(15872)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sda2(26995)
  server-vg   2   5   0 wz--n- <2,84t 36,00m /dev/sdb1(0)
```

Any ideas how to get rid of them? The system works like a charm and shows no errors in the log. Maybe it's just a display bug using the devices option? [Here](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017751) is an example of the same output which is considered regular.

Duplicate LVs have the same UUID.

Comment: "With clonezilla" - how exactly? It's a *tool*, and *how you use* the tool is of primary interest. Describe your actions.

Comment: I've added more info in the question.

Comment: Are you issuing `lvs -a -o +devices` from the host server (Proxmox) or the guest vm?

Comment: the outputs above are from VM. On the proxmox host there are no duplicate volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I could myself solve the issue by attaching a new physical disk, create a new PV, VG and LVs and copy all data over.

Free disk space is now 5G no longer 36MB.

There was obviously something wrong. I guess due to multiple clonezilla attempts without wiping the disk in between.